# Forced oscillation resonance frequencies

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, resonance

Given this forced oscillator:
$$
\ddot{x}+\gamma\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x=\frac{F(t)}{m}
$$
Where $F(t)$ is:
$$
F(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4F_0}{n\pi}\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi t}{T}\right)
\hspace{0.4cm} \text{  for }
n = 1, 3, 5, ...
$$
I start with
$
x_s(t)= A\sin(\omega t)+B\cos(\omega t)
$
And I solve them for A and B (see below), if I am not mistaken:
$$
A=\frac{F(\frac{\pi}{2\omega})}{m}
\frac{\left( \omega^2-\omega^2_0\right)}{\gamma^2\omega^2+\left( \omega^2-\omega^2_0\right)}
\hspace{0.2cm},\hspace{0.2cm}
B=\frac{F(\frac{\pi}{2\omega})}{m}
\frac{\gamma\omega}{\gamma^2\omega^2+\left( \omega^2-\omega^2_0\right)}
$$

Is this solution valid?

How can I calculate the resonance frequency? Because it seems that it is not $\omega=\omega_0$

Is there more than one resonance frequency?

My calculations
$$
\dot{x}_s=\omega A\cos(\omega t)-\omega B \sin(\omega t)
~~,~~~~
\ddot{x}_s=-\omega^2 A\sin(\omega t)-\omega^2 B \cos(\omega t)
$$
$$
\ddot{x}+\gamma\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x=\frac{F(t)}{m}\\
\!\!\!\! 
=-\omega^2 A\sin(\omega t)-\omega^2 B \cos(\omega t)
+\gamma\omega A\cos(\omega t)-\gamma \omega B \sin(\omega t)
+\omega_0^2A\sin(\omega t)+\omega_0^2B\cos(\omega t),
$$
and I solve for A and B  at $t=0$ and $t=\frac{\pi}{2\omega}$.

Comment: You can replicate the special cases in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Driven_harmonic_oscillators)? This is a subject covered extensively in texts.

Comment: There doesn't show a solution similar to Asin()+Bcos(). i'm asking if this could be done this way. Also, if the system is solved like this, could we find more than one resonance frequency?

Comment: You are mistaken in the particulars of your solution. But... after you solve the two algebraic equations right, can you guarantee that your solution works for $t=\pi/4\omega $? At other times around the circle?

Comment: [Square wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave#Fourier_analysis).

Comment: I think that part, with the Fourier series of sins, is correct. Still struggling with the resonance frequency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absorb the superfluous parameter *m* into your r.h.s. driving term, an obvious [square wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave#Fourier_analysis) with an infinity of harmonics,
$$
\ddot{x}+\gamma\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x=  \sum_{n=1,3,5...}^{\infty}\frac{4F_0}{n\pi}\sin\left( n\omega t\right),$$ where I've defined $\omega\equiv 2\pi/T$,
not your Ansatz parameter.

From the linearity of the equation, and the ultimate vanishing of the  transient solution of the damped undriven component, you realize you only need solve *one* problem, e.g. the leading harmonic *ω*, replicate/adapt the solution for each one *nω*, and add all of them together (an infinity) to get the most general solution of the full problem.

So you really only need solve the customary
$$\ddot{x}+\gamma\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x=   \frac{4F_0}{\pi}\sin\left( \omega t\right),$$
which you started doing with an ansatz of frequency *ω*, except for the full driving term, which cannot work. The steady-state solution is, then, taking the *t=0* limit into consideration,
$$
x= -\frac{4F_0}{\pi}\left ( \sin(\omega t)\frac{\omega^2-\omega_0^2}{(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)^2+\gamma^2\omega^2}+ \cos(\omega t)\frac{\gamma\omega}{(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)^2+\gamma^2\omega^2} \right )\\ \equiv
\frac{4F_0}{\pi\sqrt{(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)^2+\gamma^2\omega^2}}\bigl ( \sin(\omega t)\cos \phi  + \cos(\omega t)\sin \phi   \bigr ) \\
= \frac{4F_0}{\pi\sqrt{(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)^2+\gamma^2\omega^2}} \sin(\omega t + \phi)   ~  , \leadsto \\
\bullet ~~~~~~~~\tan \phi ={ \gamma \omega\over \sqrt{(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)^2+\gamma^2\omega^2}. }~, 
$$
as customary.

The minimum of the square root denominator of the amplitude is at
$$
\omega=\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\gamma^2/2}~,
$$
the resonant frequency of a *single* harmonic forcer. It is slightly *below* the natural frequency $\omega_0$ for weak friction.

Now repeat all this (in your mind) for a single forcing term of the form
$ \frac{4F_0}{n\pi}\sin\left(n \omega t\right)$, and add all these solutions to the above, by linearity, to get the general steady-state solution (that is, ignore the transient). Note each *n* will have a characteristic, *different* phase, and a characteristic resonance frequency at 1/*n* of the above resonant frequency. Each term will be suppressed by 1/*n*. Because of the different phases, all near π/4 at resonance, there won't be any mode-locking making these lower resonant frequencies invisible. In practice, you see the fundamental harmonic resonance slightly below  $\omega_0$, but also the next odd harmonic resonance at somewhat below  $\omega_0/3$ !

I'm sure there are better graphics sites than [this one](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2020/09/19/driving-oscillations-with-square-waves/), but I didn't want to bother looking for them. If all of the above is not self-evident, hit the reviews, Butikov (2004), "Square-wave excitation of a linear oscillator", *American Journal of Physics* **72**  (4) 469-476.